# grouped message by date and display in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, tableheader

I am creating chat app with my backend web-service and all things are going good i have just one issue is that i am getting all messages when i call `API` but now i want to filter messages to date wise like today is 30th Dec 2020 than i want to show date in tableview header and than messages here is my json response

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "status" : true,
  "data" : [
    {
      "gig_status" : 1,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "25 Dec 2020",
      "message_id" : 95,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-24T12:58:58.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 43,
      "gig_notes" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 1,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "28 Dec 2020",
      "message_id" : 117,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T04:45:04.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 50,
      "gig_notes" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "31 Dec 2020",
      "message_id" : 118,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:04:19.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 62,
      "gig_notes" : "new ro ak"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 1,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "31 Dec 2020",
      "message_id" : 119,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:11:01.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 62,
      "gig_notes" : "new ro ak"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "02 Jan 2021",
      "message_id" : 120,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:13:45.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 70,
      "gig_notes" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "02 Jan 2021",
      "message_id" : 121,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:15:20.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 70,
      "gig_notes" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "02 Jan 2021",
      "message_id" : 122,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:23:12.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 70,
      "gig_notes" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "gig_status" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "name" : "Artist",
      "image_url" : "",
      "message" : null,
      "from_me" : 1,
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "02 Jan 2021",
      "message_id" : 123,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:26:25.000000Z",
      "type" : 2,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 70,
      "gig_notes" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "type" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 124,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 70,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "02 Jan 2021",
      "gig_notes" : "Test",
      "message" : null,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T05:32:07.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : 2,
      "from_me" : 1
    },
    {
      "type" : "3",
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 125,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : null,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "01 Jan 1970",
      "gig_notes" : null,
      "message" : null,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T06:02:42.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609135362.png",
      "gig_status" : null,
      "from_me" : 0
    },
    {
      "type" : "3",
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 126,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : null,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "01 Jan 1970",
      "gig_notes" : null,
      "message" : null,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T06:21:48.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609136508.png",
      "gig_status" : null,
      "from_me" : 0
    },
    {
      "type" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 127,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 70,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "02 Jan 2021",
      "gig_notes" : "Test",
      "message" : null,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T07:32:50.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : 1,
      "from_me" : 1
    },
    {
      "type" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 128,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 73,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "10 Jan 2021",
      "gig_notes" : "Test",
      "message" : null,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T10:25:51.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : 1,
      "from_me" : 1
    },
    {
      "type" : 2,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 129,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : 74,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "19 May 2021",
      "gig_notes" : "Tehsgsbs",
      "message" : null,
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-28T10:28:14.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : 1,
      "from_me" : 1
    },
    {
      "type" : 0,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 136,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : null,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "01 Jan 1970",
      "gig_notes" : null,
      "message" : "test",
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-29T08:36:37.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : null,
      "from_me" : 0
    },
    {
      "type" : 0,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 139,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : null,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "01 Jan 1970",
      "gig_notes" : null,
      "message" : "ccgg",
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-30T05:09:13.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : null,
      "from_me" : 0
    },
    {
      "type" : 0,
      "photo" : "http:\/\/vebbuilders.co.uk\/ugigs_app\/public\/uploads\/users\/34-1609139138.png",
      "message_id" : 140,
      "star_rating" : null,
      "gig_id" : null,
      "name" : "Artist",
      "id" : 34,
      "gig_date" : "01 Jan 1970",
      "gig_notes" : null,
      "message" : "Hello",
      "msg_timestamp" : "2020-12-30T06:56:41.000000Z",
      "image_url" : "",
      "gig_status" : null,
      "from_me" : 0
    }
  ],
  "message" : ""
}
```

and here is the my function in which i am calling webservice

```
func calllMessageAPI(){
        showLoader(title: "Please Wait...", controller: self)
        let params = ["id": self.id] as [String : Any]
        guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") else { return }
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
        print(headers)
        AF.request(chatdetail, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let value):
                let json  = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                let data = json["data"]
                if data.isEmpty{
                    
                }else{
                    self.messageData.removeAll()
                    data.array?.forEach({ (mList) in
                        let m_list = NewMessageModel(message: mList["message"].stringValue, type: mList["type"].stringValue, star_rating: mList["star_rating"].doubleValue, gig_notes: mList["gig_notes"].stringValue, gig_status: mList["gig_status"].stringValue, name: mList["name"].stringValue, from_me: mList["from_me"].stringValue, message_id: mList["message_id"].stringValue, msg_timestamp: mList["msg_timestamp"].stringValue, gig_id: mList["gig_id"].stringValue, id: mList["id"].stringValue, image_url: mList["image_url"].stringValue, gig_date: mList["gig_date"].stringValue, photo: mList["photo"].stringValue)
                        self.messageData.insert(m_list, at: 0)
                    })
                    let groupedByLength = Dictionary(grouping: data) {
                    dayMonthYearDateDescription(date: parseDate(value: (($0["msg_timestamp"] as? String)!))) //Getting error here
                        
                    }
                }
                self.tblListView.reloadData()
                hideLoader(controller: self)
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                hideLoader(controller: self)
            }
            
        })
    }
```

and here is my model class for parsing json data

```
class NewMessageModel: NSObject{
    var message: String?
    var type: String?
    var star_rating: Double?
    var gig_notes: String?
    var gig_status: String?
    var name: String?
    var from_me: String?
    var message_id: String?
    var msg_timestamp: String?
    var gig_id: String?
    var id: String?
    var image_url: String?
    var gig_date: String?
    var photo: String?
    
    init(message: String,type: String,star_rating: Double,gig_notes: String,gig_status: String,name: String,from_me: String,message_id: String,msg_timestamp: String,gig_id: String,id: String,image_url: String,gig_date: String,photo: String) {
        self.message = message
        self.type = type
        self.star_rating = star_rating
        self.gig_notes = gig_notes
        self.gig_status = gig_status
        self.name = name
        self.from_me = from_me
        self.message_id = message_id
        self.msg_timestamp = msg_timestamp
        self.gig_id = gig_id
        self.id = id
        self.image_url = image_url
        self.gig_date = gig_date
        self.photo = photo
    }
}
```

now i want to filter message `msg_timestamp` which i am getting in my json response as i am new to swift i have no idea that how to filter messages by `msg_timestamp` so any please help me to solve this out

Comment: someone please help me i am stuck

Comment: Hint: `DateFormatter`.

Comment: @ElTomato thank you for hint but can you tell me more about this as i am new to swift

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268081/11471446) interface to map the object.

Example:

```
struct Movies: Codable {
   
   var name : String?
   var description : String?
   var actors : [String]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "name"
    case description = "description"
    case actors = "actors"
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.name = try response.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .name)
    self.description = try response.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    self.actors = try response.decode([String].self, forKey: .actors)
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try response.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
    try response.encode(self.description, forKey: .description)
    try response.encode(self.actors, forKey: .actors)
  }
}
```

To map this object in Alamofire you can use [responseDecodable](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-decodable-handler) method.

Example:

```
struct HTTPBinResponse: Decodable { let url: String }

AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseDecodable(of: HTTPBinResponse.self) { response in
    debugPrint("Response: \(response)")
}
```

Convert string date to `Date` object using:

```swift
let isoDate = "2020-12-30T06:56:41.000000Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
```

And then you will be able to compare that dates. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) you have description of the `Date` object. So then you can use [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method on that array.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

**jsonDataa is your data array of messages**

```
let groupedByLength = Dictionary(grouping: jsonDataa) {
        dayMonthYearDateDescription(date: parseDate(value: ($0["msg_timestamp"] as? String)!))
        
    }
```

converting string to Date and formatting

```
func parseDate(value:String) -> Date? {
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
   if let parsedDate = formatter.date(from: value) {return parsedDate}
   return nil
}

func dayMonthYearDateDescription(date: Date?) -> String? {
    guard let date = date else {
        return nil
    }
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

**Usage in your functions**

```
func calllMessageAPI(){
    showLoader(title: "Please Wait...", controller: self)
    let params = ["id": self.id] as [String : Any]
    guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") else { return }
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
    print(headers)
    AF.request(chatdetail, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let data = json["data"]
            if data.isEmpty{
                
            }else{
                let groupedByLength = Dictionary(grouping: data.array) {
        dayMonthYearDateDescription(date: parseDate(value: ($0["msg_timestamp"] as? String)!))
                self.messageData.removeAll()
                data.array?.forEach({ (mList) in
                    let m_list = NewMessageModel(message: mList["message"].stringValue, type: mList["type"].stringValue, star_rating: mList["star_rating"].doubleValue, gig_notes: mList["gig_notes"].stringValue, gig_status: mList["gig_status"].stringValue, name: mList["name"].stringValue, from_me: mList["from_me"].stringValue, message_id: mList["message_id"].stringValue, msg_timestamp: mList["msg_timestamp"].stringValue, gig_id: mList["gig_id"].stringValue, id: mList["id"].stringValue, image_url: mList["image_url"].stringValue, gig_date: mList["gig_date"].stringValue, photo: mList["photo"].stringValue)
                    self.messageData.insert(m_list, at: 0)
                })
//Here is usage
                let groupedByLength = Dictionary(grouping: data) {
                dayMonthYearDateDescription(date: parseDate(value: (($0["msg_timestamp"] as? String)!))) //Getting error here
                    
                }
            }
            self.tblListView.reloadData()
            hideLoader(controller: self)
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            hideLoader(controller: self)
        }
        
    })
}
```

Result:

```
[Optional("28 december 2020"): [["photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "star_rating": nil, "image_url": Optional(""), "gig_date": Optional("28 Dec 2020"), "gig_id": Optional(50), "name": Optional("Artist"), "type": Optional(2), "message_id": Optional(117), "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "gig_status": Optional(1), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T04:45:04.000000Z"), "from_me": Optional(1), "id": Optional(34), "message": nil], ["star_rating": nil, "image_url": Optional(""), "name": Optional("Artist"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:04:19.000000Z"), "gig_date": Optional("31 Dec 2020"), "gig_status": Optional(2), "message_id": Optional(118), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "type": Optional(2), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_notes": Optional("new ro ak"), "id": Optional(34), "gig_id": Optional(62), "message": nil], ["message_id": Optional(119), "type": Optional(2), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_status": Optional(1), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "gig_id": Optional(62), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:11:01.000000Z"), "image_url": Optional(""), "message": nil, "name": Optional("Artist"), "gig_date": Optional("31 Dec 2020"), "star_rating": nil, "id": Optional(34), "gig_notes": Optional("new ro ak")], ["gig_id": Optional(70), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "message_id": Optional(120), "type": Optional(2), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "name": Optional("Artist"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:13:45.000000Z"), "gig_date": Optional("02 Jan 2021"), "gig_status": Optional(2), "id": Optional(34), "message": nil, "image_url": Optional(""), "star_rating": nil], ["message_id": Optional(121), "image_url": Optional(""), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_id": Optional(70), "gig_status": Optional(2), "name": Optional("Artist"), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "id": Optional(34), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:15:20.000000Z"), "star_rating": nil, "type": Optional(2), "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "gig_date": Optional("02 Jan 2021"), "message": nil], ["name": Optional("Artist"), "image_url": Optional(""), "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "id": Optional(34), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "gig_date": Optional("02 Jan 2021"), "message": nil, "type": Optional(2), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:23:12.000000Z"), "gig_status": Optional(2), "message_id": Optional(122), "star_rating": nil, "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_id": Optional(70)], ["id": Optional(34), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "message": nil, "name": Optional("Artist"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:26:25.000000Z"), "type": Optional(2), "gig_date": Optional("02 Jan 2021"), "image_url": Optional(""), "star_rating": nil, "message_id": Optional(123), "gig_id": Optional(70), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_status": Optional(2), "gig_notes": Optional("Test")], ["message": nil, "gig_date": Optional("02 Jan 2021"), "star_rating": nil, "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T05:32:07.000000Z"), "gig_status": Optional(2), "image_url": Optional(""), "type": Optional(2), "message_id": Optional(124), "name": Optional("Artist"), "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_id": Optional(70), "id": Optional(34)], ["gig_notes": nil, "gig_date": Optional("01 Jan 1970"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T06:02:42.000000Z"), "gig_status": nil, "id": Optional(34), "gig_id": nil, "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "message_id": Optional(125), "message": nil, "star_rating": nil, "image_url": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609135362.png"), "type": Optional("3"), "name": Optional("Artist"), "from_me": Optional(0)], ["message_id": Optional(126), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "gig_status": nil, "from_me": Optional(0), "gig_notes": nil, "message": nil, "image_url": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609136508.png"), "gig_date": Optional("01 Jan 1970"), "id": Optional(34), "star_rating": nil, "name": Optional("Artist"), "gig_id": nil, "type": Optional("3"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T06:21:48.000000Z")], ["name": Optional("Artist"), "message_id": Optional(127), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T07:32:50.000000Z"), "star_rating": nil, "gig_id": Optional(70), "gig_status": Optional(1), "type": Optional(2), "message": nil, "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "from_me": Optional(1), "id": Optional(34), "gig_date": Optional("02 Jan 2021"), "image_url": Optional("")], ["gig_date": Optional("10 Jan 2021"), "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "gig_id": Optional(73), "from_me": Optional(1), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "image_url": Optional(""), "star_rating": nil, "name": Optional("Artist"), "gig_status": Optional(1), "message": nil, "id": Optional(34), "message_id": Optional(128), "type": Optional(2), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T10:25:51.000000Z")], ["message_id": Optional(129), "type": Optional(2), "id": Optional(34), "gig_id": Optional(74), "from_me": Optional(1), "gig_status": Optional(1), "gig_date": Optional("19 May 2021"), "message": nil, "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-28T10:28:14.000000Z"), "gig_notes": Optional("Tehsgsbs"), "name": Optional("Artist"), "image_url": Optional(""), "star_rating": nil]], Optional("24 december 2020"): [["message": nil, "gig_notes": Optional("Test"), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "message_id": Optional(95), "gig_id": Optional(43), "gig_status": Optional(1), "from_me": Optional(1), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-24T12:58:58.000000Z"), "id": Optional(34), "gig_date": Optional("25 Dec 2020"), "name": Optional("Artist"), "star_rating": nil, "type": Optional(2), "image_url": Optional("")]], Optional("30 december 2020"): [["gig_id": nil, "gig_notes": nil, "message": Optional("ccgg"), "message_id": Optional(139), "image_url": Optional(""), "name": Optional("Artist"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-30T05:09:13.000000Z"), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "type": Optional(0), "from_me": Optional(0), "star_rating": nil, "gig_date": Optional("01 Jan 1970"), "gig_status": nil, "id": Optional(34)], ["type": Optional(0), "from_me": Optional(0), "gig_date": Optional("01 Jan 1970"), "name": Optional("Artist"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-30T06:56:41.000000Z"), "gig_status": nil, "message": Optional("Hello"), "image_url": Optional(""), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "message_id": Optional(140), "gig_notes": nil, "id": Optional(34), "gig_id": nil, "star_rating": nil]], Optional("29 december 2020"): [["gig_date": Optional("01 Jan 1970"), "message_id": Optional(136), "photo": Optional("http://vebbuilders.co.uk/ugigs_app/public/uploads/users/34-1609139138.png"), "image_url": Optional(""), "message": Optional("test"), "type": Optional(0), "name": Optional("Artist"), "msg_timestamp": Optional("2020-12-29T08:36:37.000000Z"), "id": Optional(34), "gig_id": nil, "from_me": Optional(0), "gig_notes": nil, "star_rating": nil, "gig_status": nil]]]
```

Comment: i tried but i am getting error like this `Value of type '(String, JSON)' has no subscripts`

Comment: add sample how u using it?

Comment: First parse you json string into json object or json array fetch data from object and use that data as jsonDataa variable

Comment: please check i have updated my question i am using like that